# MongoDB - not authorized in shared cluster despite of atlasAdmin role

Tags: mongodb, authentication, shutdown

I have a problem with a shared mongodb cluster: I try to get data via the nodejs implementation of mongodb. A few days ago, it worked just fine. But now, every getmore command I send to the cluster is very, very slow. So I thought: Maybe I just have to turn it off and on again.

So I tried to connect to the cluster with the mongo shell. Everything works fine, my user has the atlasAdmin role (with can be seen via `db.getUser("admin")`), but when I try to execute commands like `db.shutdownServer()` or show users, the server tells me that I'm not authorized. Even the command "`db.auth("admin", ...pw...)`" returns 1.

After some research, I found out I have to shutdown the server to have a chance to fix this problem. But without permission, how should I do it? Is there any other possibility to perform this, like a button on the atlas webapp or something?

Answer (score 1):

Atlas is a hosted service, so the privileges are different vs. a bare metal MongoDB server. From [MongoDB Database User Privileges](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-add-mongodb-users/#Atlas-admin) This is the list of privileges of atlasAdmin:

- readWriteAnyDatabase
- readAnyDatabase
- dbAdminAnyDatabase
- clusterMonitor
- cleanupOrphaned
- enableSharding
- flushRouterConfig
- moveChunk
- splitChunk
- viewUser

`shutdown` privilege is part of the [hostManager role](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#hostManager), which is not included in the list above.

Depending on your type of Atlas deployment, here are the list of restricted commands/privileges:

- [Unsupported Commands in M0/M2/M5 Clusters](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/unsupported-commands/)
- [Unsupported Commands in M10+ Clusters](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/unsupported-commands-paid-tier-clusters/)

If you need to "turn on and off" your deployment, you might be able to use the [Test Failover](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/tutorial/test-failover/index.html) button if your type of deployment supports it. That button will step down the primary node and elect a new primary, which for most cases is almost equivalent to "turn off and on again".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But even when I don't have the hostManager role, shouldn't I be able to execute commands like show users? The problem with the very slow cluster was caused by MongoDB. They throttle the transfer speed after 10GB, which I wasn't aware of.

Comment: That would depend on your deployment. If you're in a shared deployment like M0/M2/M5 then I don't think you can see the users. What type are you using?